# how can I iterate a collection twice in freeMarker?

Tags: java, list, collections, freemarker

I'm newbie to this programming language and I have a collection named **model** and I need to go through it in 2 different macros.

I tried copying this collection into two different global variables:

```
<#global model1=model.issues>
<#global model2=model.issues>
```

then, in my first macro I do:

```
<#macro renderInformationIssues>

    <@renderTableFrame title=INFO_MESSAGES_HEADER colNames=INFO_MESSAGE_COLUMN_NAMES colGroups=["g-col-index", "g-col-message"]>

        <#list model1 as issue_info>
                ///////I PRINT SOMETHING FROM MODEL HERE/////////////
        </#list>
    </@renderTableFrame>

</#macro>
```

and in my second macro, I do:

```
<#macro renderExecutionIssues>
    hi1
   <@renderTableFrame title=EXECUTION_MESSAGES_HEADER colNames=EXECUTION_MESSAGE_COLUMN_NAMES colGroups=["g-col-index", "g-col-originator", "g-col-message"]>
    hi2
        <#list model2 as issue>
    hi3
          ///////I WANT TO PRINT SOMETHING ELSE FROM MODEL HERE/////////////
        </#list>
   </@renderTableFrame>

 </#macro>
```

The first macro I call, it shows the content, but the second macro I call (in this example, *renderExecutionIssue*, doesn't show anything. Actually, what I see in my second macro is only **hi1** and **hi2**.

Is it possible to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Those `#global`-s don't copy the collection; `model1` and `model2` will just point to the same object. However, `java.util.Collection`-s can be listed twice, so it's not necessary to copy them either. I suspect you have a `java.util.Iterator` (or `Enumeration`), as those can't be listed twice. Furthermore, it's not possible to tell if an `Iterator` returns 0 elements because it was already listed earlier, or because it was always empty. So in the second case, not knowing what happened, FreeMarker just lists 0 elements. If you want something to be listable for several times, pass a `Collection` (like a `List`) to FreeMarker, not the `Iterator`.

Comment: thank you! You are right, in one of the errors I got when trying different things I got this message saying that java.util.Iterator can't be listed twice. Could you please tell me how to pass the Collection to FreeMarker in order to make listable for many times?

Comment: If it's a `Collection` then it is listable for multiple times. `Iterator`-s aren't `Collection`-s.

Comment: oooh I see what you mean! I thought my original "model" was a collection but if I try to list it twice (without copying it or trying to copy it in the global variable), the second time I list it it's empty and I think it's because the pointer is pointing at a position that is got no data... So if it must be an iterator... is there any way to make a copy of the iterator to list it twice or convert my "model" iterator into a collection?

Comment: There's a confusing thing here with naming, as FTL doesn't have an iterator type, so Java `Iterator`-s are seen as FTL collection-s, with the anomaly that they can't be listed twice. Anyway, if you can't put a Java `Collection` into the data-model instead of an `Iterator`, then you can't solve this problem purely in the template. Though maybe in 2.3.27 I will add `?sequence`, which collects an FTL collection into an FTL sequence, and that would solve this. Though it's a bit scary as `Iterators`-s are often used because you aren't supposed to keep all the elements in the memory at once...

Comment: the original code is made to show the collection only once but now we need to showit twice, splitting the data in the collection. I'd like to try the ?sequence  option but I'm not sure about the syntax. would it be <#assign model1?sequence=model.issues> ? Thank you!

Comment: 2.3.27 is not yet released, `?sequence` is planned for that. But it would be `<#assign issuesSeq = model.issues?sequence>`. Anyway, the normal solution is modifying the Java (or whatever it is) code that fills the data-model to pass in `List` instead of that `Iterator`.

Comment: oh, I see. thanks a lot. My issue is that I've got no access to the code that fills the data-model, so I can only "play" with the freemarker.

Comment: FWIW, `?sequence` is already implemented in the development version, so it definitely comes in 2.3.27 (in early October hopefully).